# Logstash Grok pattern with multiple matches

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am attempting to write a grok expression that will result in multiple matches. I'm parsing a line that has 5 repetitions of the same pattern.

I've been able to make a simple pattern with a regex that will return multiple matches but it seems that Grok doesn't work that way. I don't really understand Ruby so I haven't really inspected the code.

Example input:

```
222444555
```

Pattern:

```
(?<number>\d{3})*
```

I would have expected output like this:

```
"number" : [
    [
        "222", "444", "555"
    ]
]
```

or something like that. Is this possible in Grok? I know I could just repeat the pattern three times, but on some lines there are an unknown number of repetitions.

Any pointers?

Comment: If there are an unknown number of repetitions, how would you set "{3}" ?

Comment: the {3} is a repetition on the \d (digit) character class. So what I'm trying to find (which is just a simplified representation) are the repetitions of 3 digits. So with the input of 333444555 i'm looking for 3 sets of digits, of three digits each.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: maybe you could convert to a number than use ruby to divide the digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a different approach. I used grok to extract the part of the line that was repeating. Then I used a `ruby {}` filter to chop the line up into parts using the scan function:

```
ruby {
    code => "event.put('segment', event.get('segments').scan(/.{3}/))
}
```

That worked really well as it created an array in the segment property, then followed by `split {}` on that field I got the multiple events that I wanted.