# How to capture all messages in a log using grok

Tags: logging, grok

I'm trying to capture all the messages in a log.

For example, we get this log that contains 6 messages.

"message":["18.59.43 STC47873  +LRGPSEVRI\u000007/29/20 18:59:43 I West Logged on to Tandem/Base24.","18.59.43 STC47873  +LRGPSEVRI\u000007/29/20 18:59:43 I West Logged off from Tandem/Base24.","18.59.43 STC47873  +LRGPSEVRI\u000007/29/20 18:59:43 I West Environment reset ok","18.59.43 STC47873  +LRGPSEVRE\u000007/29/20 18:59:43 E West Maximum resets occurred for task","18.59.43 STC47873  +LRGPSEVRE\u000007/29/20 18:59:43 E West Base24/Tandem comm error . Run job PRGSWSVR when resolved.","18.59.43 STC47873  +LRGPSEVRI\u000007/29/20 18:59:43 I West Server is ending","\u0000 "],"seq":{"w":"3","c":"32347"}}

I noticed that once my grok found a match in one of the messages, it will only display that message, in this case the first one.
Is it possible to capture all 6 and send it to Kibana?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.
I am new to grok and I tried everything I found in google but nothing seem to work for this particular case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that always will be 6 messages, you can use something like this:

```
"message":(\[%{QS:message_1},%{QS:message_2},%{QS:message_3},%{QS:message_4},%{QS:message_5},%{QS:message_6},%{QS:a_string}\]),"seq":{"w":"3","c":"32347"}}
```

If you want to separate them more, you can do this:

```
"message":(\[%{DATA:time} %{DATA:string_1} %{DATA:string_2} %{DATA:time} %{DATA:text_1},%{DATA:time} %{DATA:string_1} %{DATA:string_2} %{DATA:time} %{DATA:text_2},%{DATA:time} %{DATA:string_1} %{DATA:string_2} %{DATA:time} %{DATA:text_3},%{DATA:time} %{DATA:string_1} %{DATA:string_2} %{DATA:time} %{DATA:text_4},%{DATA:time} %{DATA:string_1} %{DATA:string_2} %{DATA:time} %{DATA:text_5},%{DATA:time} %{DATA:string_1} %{DATA:string_2} %{DATA:time} %{DATA:text_6},%{QS:a_string}\]),"seq":{"w":"3","c":"32347"}}
```

You can test it in http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The problem with the log is that it may contain different number of messages, from 1 to sometimes 20, so far i've seen.

If I do utilize your first option, can I further filter each messages down?

That is:
match => { "message_1" => "<grok pattern>"
match => { "message_2" => "<grok pattern>"
and so on and so fort.

Comment: You can't do this with a grok pattern, only with rules in your configuration file. See this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385831/logstash-grok-pattern-with-multiple-matches) With grok you can only predict the max number of messages and add this `(?:|%{QS:message},)` so your code will be `"message":(\[%{QS:message},(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)(?:|%{QS:message},)%{QS:a_string}\]),"seq":{"w":"3","c":"32347"}}` for 10 messages etc.. But you will have nulls at result

Comment: Thanks, roodyCool.
I will try to understand this suggestion and the other questions.

Comment: Hi @roodyCool.  
The grok pattern you suggested worked in grok debugger ==> (\[%{QS:user_msg1},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg2},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg3},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg4},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg5},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg6},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg7},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg8},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg9},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg10}\]),%{NOTSPACE}

Comment: Appreciate your help greatly. :)
However, when I applied it to the logstash, I'm getting the following error:
"Expected one of #, \", ', -, [, { 
    grok {
      match => { "message" => (\[%{QS:user_msg1},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg2},)(?:|%{QS:user_msg3},).....(?:|%{QS:user_msg10}\]),"%{NOTSPACE}"}
    }
I checked all [, {, }, ] and they all matched.
I tried all the suggested expected signs, but nothing.
Do you have a clue what's causing the error?