# Grok Pattern for matching group multiple times

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me on this.

So, I have the following logs/data:

```
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1000
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1001
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1002
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1003
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1004
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1005
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1006
ORA-Balance-Element () = 
  ORA-Balance-Element-Id () = 1007
```

I want to find a pattern that will match all the numbers after the equal sign (8 in total)
and get the result in a list (I will handle this list in Logstash conf).

So far I tried:

```
\s*ORA-Balance-Element %{DATA:tmp} = %{DATA:ora_balance_element}\n\s*ORA-Balance-Element-Id %{DATA:tmp} = %{DATA:ora_balance_element_id}\n
```

but this will only find me the first match (the first number, 1000).

Also, I tried:

```
(\s*ORA-Balance-Element %{DATA:tmp} = %{DATA:ora_balance_element}\n\s*ORA-Balance-Element-Id %{DATA:tmp} = %{DATA:ora_balance_element_id}\n)+
```

but again I could not be able to take all the matches. (This last one pattern returns the last match, number 1007).

The result I want is a list, e.g.

```
l = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007]
```

**Please notice that the above sample of logs is a multiline event and not many events. In logstash, it refers to one message and not multiple ones.**

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This looks like a [case here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450426/3832970), just use `/ORA-Balance-Element-Id\s*\(\)\s*=\s*(\d+)/` regex.

Comment: Hi! I tried the pattern you shared but unfortunately it's not working. Also, I looked at the post but it is about the same pattern in the same line multiple times. In my case, there is the same pattern but in different lines.

Comment: I edited the post in order to be more specific. The logs provided, in practice it's a multiline event.

Comment: Did you follow the same steps as in that thread? It is not just "trying a regex", it is a regex to be used by Ruby's `scan`.

Comment: If I use the way that is described in the thread, i.e. with `ruby` plugin and `scan` then it's working. But the above sample is part of a bigger multiline event and it would be more efficient a solution for the `grok` plugin.

Comment: perhaps with the dissect filter?

Comment: I'll try with the `dissect` plugin but I don't think that I'll get the desired results. Anyway...