# Logstash split log and insert it separately into elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I am writing a logstash config file and a log I am receiving is giving me issues, the team sent me multiple logs merged into one eg.

message:
[logitem(aaa=1, bbb=1, ccc=1),
logitem(aaa=2, bbb=2, ccc=2),
logitem(aaa=3, bbb=3, ccc=3)]

Would it be possible to split these log into 3 and insert them individually into elasticsearch? (3 records)

Comment: will they always be three items of `logitem`? or the number vary?

Comment: nope, it will not be always 3, it will vary

Comment: This should be achievable using the `split` filter plugin. If you want a detailed answer with config, you should post a better example of the event (as logstash sees it) - use the `stdout` output plugin and paste the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a ruby filter

This way should work (see comments below for discussion and refs). You might need to tweak the grok / scan regexes in a couple of places.

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => "^\[%{GREEDYDATA:logitems}\]$"
    }
}

ruby {
    code => "event.set('logitem', event.get('message').scan(/logitem\([^\)]+\)/))"
}

split {
    field => "logitem"
}

grok {
    match => {
        "logitem" => "^logitem\(aaa=%{DATA:field_a}, bbb=%{DATA:field_b}, ccc=%{DATA:field_c}\)"
    }
}
```

The intention of the scan regex is to match a string that:

- starts with `logitem`
- then a `(` character
- then one or more of any character except `)`
- ends with `)`

### Using grok

This way, surprisingly, does not work. See [this github issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/27#issuecomment-771646734) for more detail. TL;DR... grok will not put repeated matches into an array.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => "^\[*(logitem\(%{DATA:logitem}\), )*logitem\(%{DATA:logitem}\)\]$"
    }
  }
  split {
    field => "logitem"
  }
}
```

If you are sure the messages will always have the `aaa=, bbb=` format you could be more explicit.

[edits 1: marked grok method as non-working and added ruby method. 2: reordered a couple of things for better flow]

Comment: hi tomr, this almost worked! Managed to split the logs into two different entry, however the logitem regex part only takes the last 2 entry in the logitem

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450426/5060294) is a better approach?

Comment: and [this github issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/27#issuecomment-771646734) has more detail - looks like you really do need to use a `ruby` filter, surprisingly! At least, if you don't know how many times the field will repeat.

Comment: was trying out a repeating regex pattern but the ruby scan looks good, let me try it out

Comment: the ruby code method works for me, will need to get a regex expression for ruby and event.put doesnt work for me so I used event.set, would you like to update your answer? Also I wonder if your initial idea using the grok can be modified to accept a recurring pattern

Comment: Yeah, `event.set('field', 'value')` is the current syntax at the time of writing. I'll update the answer!